# Will Ubuntu Server fail to start-up if the NVIDIA drivers are broken?

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, graphics, ssh

It's been reported and I've personally experienced NVIDIA drivers 'randomly' breaking on ubuntu desktop after an `apt upgrade`, which can cause a lot of headache and fiddling around to get everything back running. Sometimes, it gets so bad that nothing seems to boot anymore.

What my question is, can the same thing happen on Ubuntu server--where there is no desktop environment, unless you install one and set it to start by default? With quarantine, I'm only able to connect to the server remotely, so I'm worried that if the NVIDIA drivers break that we won't be able to connect to the server anymore.

Essentially, what I'm wondering is if ubuntu server is more robust than ubuntu desktop when the graphics drivers break, allowing me to still SSH in and repair everything or if there's no difference?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop and Server use the same kernel and the same packages (just different combinations of packages). If you install a desktop stack on Ubuntu Server, it will generally behave like Ubuntu Desktop...including the same weaknesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think not. The problem is now fixed (for me with newest drivers) but I never had it with no gdm3! All worked without gdm3, no crashes.

And it will not fail to boot at my experience because once I had problems between iGPU activated with NVIDIA GeForce but it booted up as usual.

So you would be able to do that, to ssh into. Also as my experience, the computer just breaks after a time and you've to do a hardware reset. So it would work **with my experience**

I do not guarantee it works and - as I know **ubuntu server is almost the same as ubuntu desktop** except maybe different handlers but you also can use ubuntu desktop as server.

Comment: I think this is true, it would likely still boot or you could still SSH in at the very least. To do a thorough check regarding ubuntu desktop, I'd probably intentionally break the nvidia drivers, reboot then see if I could SSH in.